# Add/Remove Roles in Discord.py Rewrite using console input

Tags: python, console, discord, discord.py, roles

I'm working on a part of a big project where I've come to a dead end with adding and removing roles due to being a noob in discord.py.

I have setup console input which asks for User ID, Role to add/remove and then it should execute a command. The console is simply a batch file or run mode of pycharm/atom etc....
The function is not used within Discord with a command, but from the input only.
Sorry if it is a double post but I've been looking for this since 2 days now and every result gave me an error code. The function is commented and should let you know what exactly is the problem:

```
async def rolemanager():
   await client.wait_until_ready()
   function = input("Add/Remove> ")
        if function == 'add':
            person = input("User ID> ") # Uses non-changeable User ID
            personname = client.get_user(int(person)) # Converts to Name#0000
            roleadd = input("Role-Name> ") # Asks for exact role name to add
            confi = input("Are you sure? y/n > ") # Asks for confirm input
            if confi == "y": # If its confirmed:
                await client.add_roles(name=roleadd) # Error: AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
                print(f"Role {roleadd} added to user {personname}") # Prints if successful, or crashes the program
            else:
                print("Role-Add canceled.") # If canceled, shows this
                pass # Passes to restart the loop
        elif function == 'remove': # Same stuff here, but remove . .
            person = input("User ID> ")
            personname = client.get_user(int(person))
            roleremove = input("Role-Name> ")
            confi = input("Are you sure? y/n > ")
            if confi == "y":
                await client.remove_roles(name=roleremove)
                print(f"Role {roleremove} removed from user {personname}")
            else:
                print("Role-Remove canceled.")
                pass
        else:
            print(f"Wrong input, use add/remove in lower-case)
```

Complete Error:
   Task exception was never retrieved
future:  exception=AttributeError("'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_roles'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot2.py", line 42, in mainhandler
    await client.add_roles(name=roleadd)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'add_roles'

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `input` at all, as it's a blocking operation.  Instead, you should get all of that information from the user as part of the command invocation.

The problem you're experiencing is that `add_roles` is a method of `Member`, not `Client`

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import Member, Role

bot = commands.Bot("!")

@bot.command()
async def add(ctx, member: Member, role: Role):
    await member.add_roles(role)

@bot.command()
async def remove(ctx, member: Member, role: Role):
    await member.remove_roles(role)

bot.run("token")
```